# Display data dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display data from a database onto a content page using asp and C#. getting and displaying data from database onto a grid view is simple, I want something more advanced which gives me the ability to customize the layout of the data being displayed rather than data looking like its in a table.

I had in mind to create components dynamically for each item. For example, each item will have a panel, with labels(displaying data) and a button displaying more data in that same panel. Then I was going to make a sort of paging by using multiviews and hyperlinks at the bottom to change pages. the pages will increase if there are more than 10 items in one page.

What I am really asking for is what is the best solution/method to use to display data in an organized way rather than a table looking design.

Comment: In what sense are you using "asp" and "c#" together?  (you *did* tag this as `asp-classic` -- are you really not referring to ASP.NET?)

Comment: I believe the built-in `asp:ListView` has all answers to your questions.

Comment: What is "table looking design"?

Comment: @ Kirk Woll, yes that what i meant asp.net

Comment: @Peter Ritchie, how does data look when it is in a table, (rows and columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sounds like the `Repeater` Control is exactly what you're looking for.  It will allow you to specify a template for how to display a single item (which doesn't need to be rows in a table, it can be sequential panels, or whatever else you want).  You can then bind data to that repeater just as you would for a GridView.

Comment: Thank you, researched a bit on Repeater Control and looks like what I need. Thanks again

Comment: @Elemen7s No problem.  I remember it was a good day when I was first shown the Repeater control and I didn't need to mess around with dynamic controls nearly as often.

Answer (score 0):

You could build all of those features using a combination of core ASP.NET controls (Repeater, Pager, etc.) plus JavaScript and CSS, but the functionality you're asking for exists in several different third-party component suites (Telerik, DevExpress, Infragistics, ComponentOne, etc.)  You'll find varying opinions on which are better, so evaluate each and determine which best fits what you're looking for and/or what you can afford.

Do a web search for "ASP.NET controls" to see some of the more popular libraries.